# How do I get the right locks for this SQL?

Tags: sql-server, data-integrity, locks

My database is SQL Server 2005/8.  In a booking system we have a limit of 24 bookings on an event.  This code in a stored procedure checks:
- that the current user (@UserId) is not already booked on the event (@EventsID)
- that the current event has a current booking list of under 24
- inserts a new booking.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION 
IF (((select count (*) from dbo.aspnet_UsersEvents with (updlock) 
      where UserId = @UserId and EventsId = @EventsId) = 0) 
AND  ((SELECT Count(*)  FROM dbo.aspnet_UsersEvents with (updlock) 
      WHERE EventsId = @EventsId) < 24))
BEGIN
  insert into dbo.aspnet_UsersEvents (UserId, EventsId) 
      Values (@UserId, @EventsId)
END
COMMIT
```

The problem is that it is not safe.  Two users might perform the test simultaneously and conclude they can both book.  Both insert a row and we end up with 25 bookings.

Simply enclosing it in a transaction does not work.  I tried adding WITH (UPDLOCK) to the selects in the hope that one would take update locks and keep the other out.  That does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three options:

1. `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ`
2. Change the lock hint to `WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK)`
3. Add a unique constraint to dbo.aspnet_UsersEvents and a `TRY/CATCH` around the insert.

You can use the following script to confirm that the lock is taken and immediately released if you omit `HOLDLOCK`. You will also see that the lock is not released (no 'releasing lock reference on KEY' output) when `HOLDLOCK` is used.

([Gist script](https://gist.github.com/1420027))

Comment: Why so complicated? See my answer.

Comment: Because your answer is not transactionally safe. That a single statement is always consistent is a common fallacy.

Comment: Can you please point out some documentation for SQL Server's non-guarantee that a single statement is not consistent. I'm assuming he's not running at `READ UNCOMMITTED`.

Comment: Adding the HOLDLOCK hint seems to be the major part I was missing - thank you.

Comment: I tried REPEATABLE READ, but it's not actually enough. Even though the reads get the same rows as before (repeatable) they miss a new one.  Using SERIALIZABLE does work, but I'm just a little scared of SERIALIZABLE.

Comment: In fact there is a unique constraint on the composite key EventsID and UserID.  That only prevents one user booking twice on the same event.  It does not help with the 24 limit test.

Comment: @todda.speot.is I have a demo script if you want to pop into the [dba.se chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/179/the-heap)

Comment: @RichardHowells Apologies, I misunderstood the part about the event count. Glad to hear the HOLDLOCK sorts it.

Answer (score 1):

Just do it in one statement, at `READ COMMITTED` or higher.

```
INSERT dbo.aspnet_UsersEvents
       (UserId,EventsId)
OUTPUT inserted.UserEventsId -- Or whatever, just getting back one row identifies the insert was successful
SELECT @UserId
       , @EventsId
 WHERE ( SELECT COUNT (*)
           FROM dbo.aspnet_UsersEvents
          WHERE UserId = @UserId
                AND EventsId = @EventsId ) = 0
       AND ( SELECT COUNT(*)
               FROM dbo.aspnet_UsersEvents
              WHERE EventsId = @EventsId ) < 24
```

<sub>Side note: your `SELECT COUNT(*)` for duplicate checking seems excessive, personally I'd use `NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM ... WHERE UserID = ..., EventsID = ...`.</sub>

Comment: You make a useful point that an Exists test is clearer than the count.  Thank you.